# Индекс вне диапазона при использовании таблицы с двумя разными списками из массивов строк

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Есть таблица с двумя списками из строковых массивов, между которыми переключаемся посредством сегмент-контроллера. Например

```
let standingExersiseName = ["Один", "Два", "Три", "Четыре ", "Пять"]
let sittingExersiseName = ["Одинажды", "Дважды", "Трижды"]
```

В этих двух списках количество элементов в массиве разное. При нажатии на ячейку (и передаче на др контроллер) из списка с большим количеством элементов и порядковым номером больше чем элементов во втором списке (например нажимаем на ячейку "Четыре "), выдается ошибка fatal error: Index out of range. Как то можно исправить не добавляя во второй список недостающее количество элементов равное количеству из первого списка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика Ваших действий не совсем ясна, но если исправить текущее положение и оставить все как есть, можно так:

`let nameSitting = sittingExersiseName[indexpath.row % sittingExersiseName.count]`

А вообще, нужно индекс для второй таблицы передавать необходимый, а не из первой для всего.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо

Answer (score 0):

Не забывай делать reloadData после переключения сегментКонтрола.
И во всех методах для таблицы используй выбранный массив.